# Creating a custom security encoding/decoding transform

Tags: macos, osx-lion, core-foundation

I'd like to create a Base16 encoder and decoder for Lion's new `Security.framework` to complement `kSecBase32Encoding` and `kSecBase64Encoding`.  Apple's documentation shows how to write a custom transform (Caesar cipher) using `SecTransformRegister`.  As far as I can tell, custom transforms registered this way have to operate symmetrically on the data and can't be used to encode and decode data differently.  Does anyone know if writing a custom encoder/decoder is possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to tie custom encoders into `SecEncodeTransformCreate()`, which is what `kSecBase32Encoding` and the others are based on. But it's easy to create a transform that accepts a "encoding" bool and makes use of that to decide whether to encode or decode. In the CaesarTransform example, they attach an attribute called `key` with `SecTransformSetAttribute()`. You'd do the same thing, but with a bool `encode`.

And of course you could just create an encoding transform and a decoding transform.

Comment: I considered that approach but I had hoped there is a way to have a single code path for base 16, 32, and 64.  It may not be possible with the current version.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should open a radar about (bugreport.apple.com). I spoke with the Security framework team at WWDC, and these are exactly the kinds of things they want to know from the developers.

Comment: I will file a radar, but I won't hold my breath for a response.  I'm a bit jaded about Apple's bug reporter but it is still worth giving them feedback.

Comment: I've marked this as correct since, as I feared, this currently isn't possible.